# New ish battery, new alternator, battery light stays on (dim)

Tags: battery, alternator

- Battery was replaced 7-8 months ago (Interstate batteries brand)
- Got new alternator today after car died
- When picked up, battery light was faintly glowing
- Mechanic said everything was fine and it's nothing to worry about despite my protestations

... which I obviously don't buy since I'm posting here.

*What led to me getting a new alt:
Two nights ago, my battery light suddenly came on right before I parked. When I got back into my car an hour later, it wouldn't start. Made a rapid clicking noise. I was able to jump it and get it home; it shuddered dead right as I pulled in.*

*Naturally I assumed it was not the battery since it wasn't holding a charge. Took it to the mechanic today, who replaced the alternator. Got in the car and it started fine, but the battery light is still on, about half as bright as before. Light was NOT on at all before all this.*

Thoughts? Should I go to my other mechanic? Ignore the dim light until something happens? Thank you :)

**2001 Toyota RAV4**

Comment: can you loan a multimeter and check the voltage it's putting out and from the battery when the car is not running?   It's common that people are recommended to change battery when they replace the alternator, though that's not strictly necessary always.

Comment: There is something wrong, the lamp should not be lit. You should take it back.

Comment: When does the battery light start glowing? as soon as you start the engine?

Comment: Hi Mauro, yes it's basically always on once I start the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You should check battery. It may be dead as well. In Europe every battery seller can do that.

Next problem may be in auxiliary belt. May worth to change it as well. The symptoms are skweeking noises when starting / turning off and when is wet outside.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is broken wire in the alternator connector. I haven't checked the diagrams specific to your vehicle, but I believe that it is usually the white wire.

Here's the page where they describe the repair (on a Highlander, however the idea is the same): http://carspecmn.com/toyota-highlander-battery-light-on-an-unusual-repair/